# Google meet streaming through MediaRecorder APIs

Tags: mediarecorder, web-mediarecorder, mediarecorder-api, get-display-media, google-meet

I am trying to record google meet audio and video using getDisplayMedia using media options.I am able to record my screen through getDisplayMedia but unable to record voice coming in google meet. How can I use passive recording or is there any way where I can record screen, audio and video in google meet through any mechanism or code?

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({audio: true,video: true});
      let mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStreamObj);
        let chunks = [];

        mediaRecorder.start();
        console.log(mediaRecorder.state);

        mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(ev) {
            chunks.push(ev.data);
        }

        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("Stopping!");
            mediaRecorder.stop();
            console.log(mediaRecorder.state);
            mediaRecorder.onstop = (ev) => {
                let blob = new Blob(chunks, {
                    'type': 'video/mp4;'
                });
                chunks = [];
                let videoURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                console.log(videoURL);
            }
        }, 40000);
```

Comment: Did you get it working?

Comment: No it is not working

Answer (score -1):

i did it with puppeteer. i build a google meet bot who will join your meetings from google calendar and record audio + save all transcript . when meeting ends everything will be sent over email or you can see in app dashboard.

Comment: Would you be able to share the code on gist or github repo?